# Latex paint smudged onto fake river stone fireplace and mortar

Tags: painting, paint, cleaning

We hired a painter and I’m regretting our choice because he has slopped paint everywhere. I believe I can get it off most of the surfaces but I’m particularly concerned about our fireplace. It is made of faux stone and the guy did not tape it off at all. There is now dark blue paint on the faux stone and mortar. It is latex. I’m hoping to find a way to remove the paint without damaging the finish. Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use some painters tape and plastic to mask off the wall below.
2. Carefully remove the pieces of dried latex with a razor blade (If Possible).
3. Dip a toothbrush into rubbing alcohol and gently brush over the smudge.
4. Wet another toothbrush and pour dish detergent directly on the bristles.
5. Gently scrub the grout.
6. Dip the toothbrush into clean water and rinse.
7. Dab with a clean damp cloth.

Repeat as necessary. The paint will eventually all come out and you wont harm the grout.

- Send that painter a bill.

Answer (score 0):

Try both off these tricks in a discreet location first.

**Goof off** on the stone. It's extremely aggressive and evaporates quickly but it will dissolve paint with ease. If the stone is very porous it's probably not a good idea.

On the mortar you can simply scratch off the paint. If done carefully it will remove any evidence of paint.

Again try in a discreet location first, that goes with any method of removing paint from a finished surface.

Comment: What do you recommend scraping it with?

Comment: @CristydeGaray try a toothpick first, then something plastic avoid something metal unless you are very careful. Sometimes tweezers will work as the latex may pull off in bits...

Comment: It depends on how much you need to remove and how patient you are. A small screwdriver may help.